Should reference plane change its potential value if a track goes to another layer?
Assume you have a four layer board.

Signal
GND


Dielectric


VDD
Signal

And you having a track in the 4:th layer. Suddenly you're using a via to go through the 4:th layer to 1:st layer.
Question
The reference plane for the 4:th layer is the 3:rd plane, which has a potential lager than GND volt. The VDD don't have to be 3V3 volt, it can be voltage for DDR memory as well.
But once you're routing your track from 4:th layer to 1:st, you're also changing the reference plane to GND, which is now 2:nd layer.
Should you place a copper plane at the 2:nd layer which has the same voltage potential as the 3:rd layer?
Update:
This is one example where I add a copper plane and asign VDD onto it.
Now the stack is
Signal/GND
GND
GND
Signal/GND
Perhaps this is not good at all? I need to get the capacitor-effect?
The C144 is a 10 uF capacitor.

If I cover the second layer with the first layer like this.



Should you place a copper plane at the 2nd layer which has the same
voltage potential as the 3rd layer?

The plane's DC level is irrelevant.
It's the plane's proximity and AC impedance to the associated tracks that is important. That plane's capacitive connection to the actual GND plane makes it a suitable substitute for GND.
However, if the power plane voltage is noisy with respect the GND then it could cause problems. Solution is good decoupling between GND and power plane at several points.

So you're telling me that I should use the most noise free plane as the reference plane?

No, I'm not saying that. GND by default has to be the most noise-free plane and that should always be regarded as the reference plane but, it's permissible to use power planes providing they are not noisy AND, they can be made less noisy (to an acceptable level) by adding decoupling capacitors at several points @euraad

So adding copper and give it the same voltage potential, is not a common method to do, just because you want GND or VDD for a specific trace for all lines?

I don't understand what you are asking me @euraad

You're the expert here and the question is about if that method is a good practice or not.

I don't know which method you refer to. Please be clear.

I will post some screen shots. Stay tuned.

@euraad you should also take note of the comment I left under my answer on this post that you made: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/714973/is-it-possible-to-simulate-reflections-by-designing-an-rlc-transfer-function

I updated my question with an example.

Four layer boards usually have a large dielectric between layer 2 and 3. This makes the coupling between these poor.

@Tyassin Yes! But how about if I cover the second layer with the first layer. See the second image above.

@euraad if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. I'm not asking you to mark my answer as accepted of course.

@Andyaka I understand the idea now. The potential voltage of the reference plane is not relevant and the reference plane should be noise free as much as possible and very close to the signal plane. Thank you.

No, the referece plane potential does not have to match.
The signal is AC so the DC does not matter, but the two reference planes must be well coupled together.
It means that if both reterence planes are GND, you can just use GND vias between planes right next to signal vias, so that the signal going vertically between top and bottom layer, there is a top to bottom return path between layers 2 and 3.
If you have a VCC and GND as reference planes, you can provide a good coupling between them with a capacitor right near the signal vias.

So in this case, when I use plane 2 as VDD_DDR  with a coupling capacitor and the plane 1 as GND, then it's fine?
